# "mine ears"and"my ears",I should choose which one?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I just want to know between "mine ears "and "my ears ",which one is right ? Can anybody give me some reasonable explanations?

Comment: Using ***mine*** like that is archaic today - it's now only used as a possessive pronoun (i.e. - **noun**), whereas ***my*** is a "possessive **adjective**".

Comment: Both are "right," though which is more common depends on era in time and possibly on regional dialect.  Your question may be more interesting if you ask about that.  In other words, "In which regions and in which times was it more common to say "mine ears" as opposed to "my ears"?"

Comment: This has been covered by [“my” vs “mine” (adjectives vs. possessive )](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24722/my-vs-mine-adjectives-vs-possessive) on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @cobaltduck yeah! I am a Chinese who knows little English knowledge,but thanks a lot anyway .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"My" is a possessive adjective whereas "mine" is a possessive pronoun that is used in place of a noun.  Example: "Those are my dogs" versus "Those dogs are mine". Mine here means "I am the possessor".

In archaic English you hear lines like "Mine eyes have seen the glory of the coming of the Lord" where "mine" functions as a possessive adjective like "my".

There may be regional dialectical variations regarding modern usage that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "my" and "mine" mean the same thing; both are possessive adjectives. But in the past, "mine" was used before words that started with vowels, and "my" was used for words that started with consonants. The same goes for "thy" and "thine" as well. The idea is similar to that behind the articles "a" and "an."

In modern standard American English, you would not use "mine" to mean "my."

Answer (score 0):

If you're speaking after 1400 CE, "my ears" is the correct form.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=my

The difference between "my" and "mine" is that you put "my" in front of a word that belongs to you ("my ears are big"), while you use "mine" to replace the word altogether ("those big ears are mine" (i.e. "those big ears are my big ears")). The corresponding distinction with other pronouns is :

> Your X / X is yours
>   His X / X is his
>   Her X / X is hers
>   Our X / X is ours
>   Their X / X is theirs

"My" is called a **possessive determiner** (it "determines" that another word is used in a possessive sense) while "mine" is a **possessive pronoun** (like all pronouns, it is used to replace another noun).

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc